# GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException with message 'Client error

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I want to create a payment intention with the Stripe API from Laravel.

I don't get a successful payment intent, but I get this error:

DELL@DELL-PC MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/LaravelPayment

$ php artisan tinker

Psy Shell v0.11.2 (PHP 8.0.8 — cli) by Justin Hileman

> > > $stripe = new App\Services\StripeService;

=> APP\Services\StripeService {#3555}

> > > $stripe->createIntent(5.01, 'USD', 'pm_1KlyY1JJef7TvJrq8R8fD5B6');

GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException with message 'Client error: `POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:

{

"error": {

```
"code": "parameter_missing",

"doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-missing",
```

(truncated...)

'

Below, you can find my code:

```
<?php
 
namespace APP\Services;
 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 
use App\Traits\ConsumesExternalServices;
 
class StripeService
{
    use ConsumesExternalServices;
 
    protected $baseUri;
 
    protected $key;
 
    protected $secret;
 
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->baseUri = config('services.stripe.base_uri');
        $this->key = config('services.stripe.key');
        $this->secret = config('services.stripe.secret');
    }
 
    public function resolveAuthorization(&$queryParams, &$formParams, &$headers)
    {
        $headers['Authorization'] = $this->resolveAccessToken();
    }
 
    public function decodeResponse($response)
    {
        return json_decode($response);
    }
 
    public function resolveAccessToken()
    {
        return "Bearer {$this->secret}";
    }
 
    public function handlePayment(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }
 
    public function handleApproval()
    {
        //
    }
 
    public function createIntent($value, $currency, $paymentMethod)
    {
        return $this->makeRequest(
            'POST',
            '/v1/payment_intents',
            [],
            [
                'amount' => round($value * $this->resolveFactor($currency)),
                'currency' => strtolower($currency),
                'payment_method' => $paymentMethod,
                'confirmation_method' => 'manual',
            ],
        );
    }
 
    public function resolveFactor($currency)
    {
        $zeroDecimalCurrencies = ['JPY'];
 
        if (in_array(strtoupper($currency), $zeroDecimalCurrencies)) {
            return 1;
        }
 
        return 100;
    }
    
}
```

Could you please check with me what is the problem?

I've tried to debug and it seems that those values are sent correctly:

[image]

[image]

What should I do now?

Comment: Have you debugged your config to make sure that those secrets and keys are coming through? sometimes caching causes configs to cache and may not have updated. check it via tinker or even a route. e.g. `dd(config('services.stripe.key'))`

Comment: Can you include makeRequest() function as it could be there the error lies

Comment: I have debugged my config and those secrets and keys are coming through.

Comment: How should I include makeRequest() function? Please give me an example.